# oracle error while compiling procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am getting below error while creating below procedure, I have also removed most of the part from procedure and included only part which I am facing with issues. Issue is in the decode clause, please help!!!

> [Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error 84/41   PL/SQL:
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 33/4    PL/SQL: SQL Statement
>   ignored  (2: 0): Warning: compiled but with compilation errors

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ERR_OUT (
   in_Srcsyscd                    IN     VARCHAR2)
IS
   rcrdnums   VARCHAR2 (32767);
   rcrd_cnt   INT;
BEGIN
   rcrd_cnt := 500;

   SELECT RTRIM (
             XMLCAST (
                XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, RCRDNUM) ORDER BY RCRDNUM) AS CLOB),
             ',')
     INTO rcrdnums
     FROM (SELECT (ERR.RCRDNUM || ',') AS RCRDNUM
             FROM tableName ERR
                  WHERE     ROWNUM <= rcrd_cnt
                  AND   (   in_srcsyscd IS NULL
                       OR (decode (REGEXP_COUNT (in_srcsyscd, ','),0,(ERR.Srcsyscd = in_srcsyscd),                              
                                 (ERR.Srcsyscd IN
                                    (SELECT DISTINCT srcsyscd
                                       FROM tableName
                                      WHERE    srcsyscd IN
                                                  (SELECT err.srcsyscd
                                                     FROM tableName ERR
                                                          RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                                                          (    SELECT UPPER (
                                                                         REGEXP_SUBSTR (
                                                                            in_Srcsyscd,
                                                                            '[^,]+',
                                                                            1,
                                                                            LEVEL))
                                                                         CNTRY_CD
                                                                 FROM DUAL
                                                           CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (in_Srcsyscd,
                                                                         '[^,]+',
                                                                         1,
                                                                         LEVEL)
                                                                         IS NOT NULL) CNTRY_P
                                                             ON (UPPER (
                                                                    ERR.srcsyscd) !=
                                                                    CNTRY_P.CNTRY_CD))
                                            OR srcsyscd IS NULL)))))
```

Below is the where clause where i am facing issues and there is no issue with count of parenthesis that i can observe but still oracle is throwing error for this  :

```
AND   (   in_srcsyscd IS NULL
                       OR (decode (REGEXP_COUNT (in_srcsyscd, ','),0,(ERR.Srcsyscd = in_srcsyscd),                              
                                 (ERR.Srcsyscd IN
                                    (SELECT DISTINCT srcsyscd
                                       FROM AMT_OWNER.AMT_EVNT_SPND_ERR_STG
                                      WHERE    srcsyscd IN
                                                  (SELECT err.srcsyscd
                                                     FROM TableName
                                                          RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                                                          (    SELECT UPPER (
                                                                         REGEXP_SUBSTR (
                                                                            'CONCUR',
                                                                            '[^,]+',
                                                                            1,
                                                                            LEVEL))
                                                                         CNTRY_CD
                                                                 FROM DUAL
                                                           CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (
                                                                         'CONCUR',
                                                                         '[^,]+',
                                                                         1,
                                                                         LEVEL)
                                                                         IS NOT NULL) CNTRY_P
                                                             ON (UPPER (
                                                                    ERR.srcsyscd) !=
                                                                    CNTRY_P.CNTRY_CD))
                                            OR srcsyscd IS NULL)))))
```

Comment: 'missing right parenthesis' gives you all. If you use notepad++ or some help with the parenthesis, you'll find that you miss one last parenthesis on
..."OR srcsyscd IS NULL))))))"

Comment: This seems not to be a parenthesis issues.

Answer (score 0):

The complex statement in your decode is syntactically incorrect.
You cannot write:

```
decode(a,b,c,(err.srcsyscd in ...))
```

I would suggest you replace the decode with a case statement.  The logic will be clearer to read and maintain.

Example (not sure if this is the correct logic for you)

```
 where rownum <= rcrd_cnt
   and (case
          when in_srcsyscd is null then
           1
          else
          when regexp_count(in_srcsyscd, ',') = 0 then
           case
              when err.srcsyscd = in_srcsyscd then
               1
              else
               0
           end
          else
          when err.srcsyscd in
               (select distinct srcsyscd
                  from tablename
                 where srcsyscd in
                       (select err.srcsyscd
                          from tablename err
                         right outer join (select upper(regexp_substr(in_srcsyscd, '[^,]+', 1, level)) cntry_cd
                                            from dual
                                          connect by regexp_substr(in_srcsyscd, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null) cntry_p
                            on (upper(err.srcsyscd) != cntry_p.cntry_cd))
                    or srcsyscd is null) then
           1
          else
           0
       end) = 1
```

Comment: can you please write above logic using case